# Charging paused. Battery temperature too high or too low

Tags: battery, charging

I have a Samsung Galaxy player that has been giving me the message "Charging paused. Battery temperature too high or too low". I left it unplugged and powered down all night, and it still gave me the message as soon as I turned it on. The battery should be at room temperature. I've turned it off and on several times. I've tried removing the battery and putting it back. I have no idea what's wrong. It's been working fine for the past 9 months. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you checked [“Charging paused. Battery temperature too high” while connected to car charger](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26998/charging-paused-battery-temperature-too-high-while-connected-to-car-charger) if it might apply? Though this is probably another cause, as you explicitly state it happens also just after power-up.

Comment: Did you turned ON Wi-Fi Hotspot / MobileAP?

Comment: Probably your battery is dead, get a cheap replacement on ebay which will cost you some 6-15EUR. @SachinShekhar: the Galaxy Player has no GSM, it's only for surfing, music and such.

Comment: @ce4 Alright. Didn't know about that.. thanks. :)

Comment: @Patrick : did you find out what happened ? I'm stuck with the exactly same problem. I am about to do a reset factory and if fails I'll try to replace USB charge connector. Before that, I would like to know what about your phone..

Comment: @Delphine what exactly happened to your phone before it started displaying this message? Did it fall/ come into contact with water/ was it opened?

Comment: @user145490 : Nothing at all ! I loved my phone, never crashed, never fallen into water.. Maybe it was because I played with my phone during charging.. Or I charged it every night.. :/ I give up and I bought a new one. Only thing which solved this issue for 2month and half was : charging my battery in an external charger. After that, everything went back to normal. Issue reappeared after 2 month and a half but with the fact that EVERY application were closed automatically due to "hot" battery.. :/

Comment: @Delphine haha. Well I had the same problem except mine was with my S5. It fell one time then all hell came loose. It wouldn't open apps 'battery too hot' it also wouldn't charge 'battery too cold'. However holding the battery in hand, it wasn't ever too hot or too cold. I took it to Samsung repair centre and the technician assigned to me was actually very helpful. Apparently the fall had damaged the motherboard and the charging port. I'm not sure the exact term he used for the specific part, but in summary the phone has 2 sensors one to monitor internal components temperature...

Comment: @Delphine **cont** and another to monitor battery temperature so that charge can be disconnected when the bat gets too hot. Basically they were both damaged and are permanently fixed to the motherboard. Meaning for repair to happen, they'd have to change the motherboard

Comment: @user145490 Mine was a S5 too ;p ! Glad to hear an official explanation. I though about changing "USB connector" (50€ in France) but as I was not sure about the reason and because warranty was over I bought a new one. Maybe my phone felt once but issue did not appeared just after the fall.. Too bad. My new one is a S7 but my S5 still stays on my bedside table.. !

Answer (score 7):

AFAIK the temperature sensor that measures the battery is built-in (in the battery). In your case either the battery is defective, because it get's to hot immediately when charging *or* the sensor is defective. Either way, I think you have to replace the battery with a new one.

Before you replace the battery you should rule out a software error by doing a factory reset to see if the problem persists.

Comment: It's been fine for months, and I don't think it ever overheated. Why wshould it be having issues like that now?

Comment: Things tend to break from one moment to another.

Comment: Nope. Just bought a brand new battery and having the same problem. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post but, I just had this problem and found a good solution so thought I'd post the answer here in case someone else is looking for the same help.

Power down the phone.
Take the battery out for 20+ seconds.
Plug in the charger.
Put the battery back in.
Turn the phone back on.

Comment: Same problem (battery temperature too low), but neither trying with other batteries nor trying to remove the battery for a few minutes changed anything

Answer (score 1):

I left my phone in the car on a cold night, and it said it couldn't charge because the temperature was too high or too low. All I did was let it warm up in my house for 15 minutes. Then, I plugged it in, and everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

**For those who have tried multiple batteries,**

I have multiple Samsung phones, **I use the wall charger to avoid charging my phone. It was $15** on ebay, and it may be a viable workaround and/or solution outside of replacing the motherboard.

These wall chargers will charge your battery no matter what, you can confirm this by looking at the pins on the image below. **If the third pin not present**, the charger does not check battery stats before charging.

[image]

(I consider this a solution, because it takes advantage of the removable battery feature, and the chargers come in packs of three batteries so you'll never be stuck to an outlet again.)

Hope this helps.