# Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 charging paused, battery temperature low

Tags: charging, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1

I have a new Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1. I recently bought it online. It was working fine, but now the tablet is not charging and keeps giving the error 'battery temperature low'. I tried charging it by switching the tablet off, but then it gives a yellow error sign.

Comment: Try charging in safe mode and report your findings.

Comment: It still gives error "charging paused, battery temperature low"

Comment: A rather similar question was asked [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/28649/7574). Did the answers given there work for you? If not, please edit your question and explain how your situation is different

Answer (score 0):

I can only get min to charge in safe mode. In normal mode it makes the charger connect sound, immediately followed by charger disconnect sound. To start in safe mode simply power down and restart, it will first show static Samsung logo, and then start animated Samsung logo, when second logo starts press and hold volume down. The screen will go slightly grey after a few seconds. You can leave the button then, it will start in safe mode. 
Only workaround seems to be rolling back to Kit Kat.