# phone is stuck on welcome screen (samsung galaxy note 2) when using other battery

Tags: battery, samsung-galaxy-note-2

hi i have a samsung galaxy note 2 n7105 and i have 2 batteries. when i am using battery A, everything boots okay but when i use battery B it is stuck at the samsung logo and will not go on. sometimes it reboots and just end up stuck again at the samsung logo. i just want to know what is the reason for this and hoping that there's some kind of fix for this. your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like your battery doesn't have enough charge, or is a crap knockoff. Do you have an external battery charger for battery B? See [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/137642/101950) for tips on a battery charger w/o the third pin.

Answer (score 0):

When I worked at a cell phone shop as the "tech", I had this exact same thing happen, except with a Samsung Galaxy S3 or 4, I can't remember which. In my case, both batteries were apparently the same official Samsung OEM battery, however upon careful examination side-by-side, there were tiny differences in how the non-working battery looked as compared to every other one that I could find. I finally realized that the non-working battery was NOT an actual OEM battery; it was a knock-off designed to pass as an OEM. So, the non-working battery, in my case, was a counterfeit. Basically, this behavior means that you have a faulty battery, whether it is OEM or fake. I've never had an OEM battery do this but that's not to say that it might not happen with them or with legit, non-OEM batteries as well. The only time it happened to me, though, was with a counterfeit, so...

Comment: my faulty battery was working well before.

Comment: Yeah, my theory is that the knock-offs go bad in a particular way due to their differences in manufacturing that an oem doesn't.

Comment: my mother bought me the spare battery and i'm not sure if it's a counterfeit or not and also i could not identify which is original and which is the spare. all i know is that it worked well since it was bought  and it became defective last november or december last year. could it be that it became defective because of constantly changing custom roms, rooting and unrooting? ('cause i'm really fond of doing those)

Comment: Also, it is an accepted fact in the cell phone world that a defective battery can cause your phone to reset itself although I myself do not agree with what they say. They say a defective battery can be identified by the fact that it is bulging, however I have had many batteries that had a bulge and were never the cause of any problems other than less battery life. Also, the battery that DID do this to me was, in fact, NOT bulging. This theory says that a defective battery will not be able to supply the power needed for an instant or two, which makes the phone reset. Hope this helps

Comment: I don't really see how your battery could become defective from anything rooting and installing any custom roms might do. I have much experience with rooting and custom roms on a BUNCH of different phones and I find it highly unlikely that you could have screwed up your battery in such a way. I suppose it might be somehow POSSIBLE if you wrote your own rom and messed AT LENGTH with the charging characteristics or something,  but I'd bet money you didn't do it.

Comment: haha yeah i didn't. so i guess the battery just became defective? i checked today which one is the OEM and which is not and found out that the defective battery was in fact the OEM (it had the date of manufacturing and the working one doesn't have any).
thought i really took good care of the batteries for it not to reach that far